# Created Structure for USSD type menu

Tags: java, algorithm, ussd

I have to implement the USSD flow:

which should have below structure:

```
            a    
          /
         a-- b
        / \  
            c
      /  
      a---b
   /   \
  /      c 
 /         a
/       /
Hi-----b---b
        \
           c
```

not able to draw it clearly but it is somewhat like if user pressed Hi then he will get 3 options a,b,c each associated with certain value and if he select one of them then again he gets some more values with tag a,b,c ... on the basis of selected option so the tree grows like this we can assume it as a sort of generic tree structure.

```
So I think about it and then come to solution sharing the same in the below steps:

1). Stored the static data/sub options into the map. 
2). Then Stored those maps into map of map to link sub options with options
3). So I have created map of map is this structure is good please share ur inputs??

4). and for processing considering one map into the memory for further actions 


Below is there my implementations, can you please share your inputs, what can be best practice or best way to write this code.





 public class USSDImpl {

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            Map<String,String> hiSubOptions = new HashMap<String,String>();
            hiSubOptions.put("a","Balance");
            hiSubOptions.put("b","Prepaid");
            hiSubOptions.put("c","Last3Transactions");

            Map<String,String> balanceSubOptions = new HashMap<String,String>();
            balanceSubOptions.put("a","Saving");
            balanceSubOptions.put("b","Current");
            balanceSubOptions.put("c","Other");

            Map<String,String> prepaidSubOptions = new HashMap<String,String>();
            prepaidSubOptions.put("a","Idea");
            prepaidSubOptions.put("b","Airtel");
            prepaidSubOptions.put("c","Tata");

            Map<String,String> sp1SubOptions = new HashMap<String,String>();
            sp1SubOptions.put("a","10");
            sp1SubOptions.put("b","100");
            sp1SubOptions.put("c","1000");

            Map<String,String> sp2SubOptions = new HashMap<String,String>();
            sp2SubOptions.put("a","15");
            sp2SubOptions.put("b","150");
            sp2SubOptions.put("c","1500");

            Map<String,String> sp3SubOptions = new HashMap<String,String>();
            sp3SubOptions.put("a","20");
            sp3SubOptions.put("b","200");
            sp3SubOptions.put("c","2000");

            Map<String,HashMap<String,String>> optionToSubOptions = new HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>();
            optionToSubOptions.put("hi",(HashMap<String, String>) hiSubOptions);
            optionToSubOptions.put("balance",(HashMap<String, String>) balanceSubOptions);
            optionToSubOptions.put("prepaid",(HashMap<String, String>) prepaidSubOptions);
            optionToSubOptions.put("idea",(HashMap<String, String>) sp1SubOptions);
            optionToSubOptions.put("airtelt",(HashMap<String, String>) sp2SubOptions);
            optionToSubOptions.put("tata",(HashMap<String, String>) sp3SubOptions);


            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            Map<String,String> currentOptions = new HashMap<String, String>();


                //String previousMessage = "hi";
                while(scanner.hasNext())
                {   String userInput = scanner.next();
                    if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Hi"))
                    {

                        currentOptions =  optionToSubOptions.get(userInput.toLowerCase());
                        System.out.println(currentOptions);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //validateOption(userInput);
                        currentOptions = optionToSubOptions.get(currentOptions.get(userInput.toLowerCase()).toLowerCase());
                        System.out.println(currentOptions);
                    }
                }



        }

    }
```

Further i would like to extend this for multiple user in an concurrent way, so to accommodate it I have to create one more map of map, whose key will be the credential of that user and value will be current options.

So please share your inputs

Comment: Did you get the solution?